# Is it safe to delete memory with a pointer of different type than the used in new?

Tags: c++, new-operator, heap-memory, delete-operator

Is the following code safe? Is there a reference to C++ standard addressing this question?

```
// SomeStruct is POD: no constructors or destructor
SomeStruct *pSS = new SomeStruct();
void *pV = reinterpret_cast<void*>(pSS);
delete pV;
```

Comment: deleting a `void*` will not call the original object's destructor

Comment: @NathanOliver, that is ok because PODs are in focus (see a comment in the code example). So there is no destructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only OK when:

1. you delete a pointer-to-base,
2. *and* that base class has a virtual destructor.

Otherwise, you're in the land of illegal code and undefined behaviour.

C++14 5.3.5/2

> If the operand has a class type, the operand is converted to a pointer type by calling the above-mentioned conversion function, and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section. In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (*delete array*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array *new-expression*. If not, the behavior is undefined. [ *Note:* this means that the syntax of the *delete-expression* must match the type of the object allocated by `new`, not the syntax of the *new-expression*. — *end note* ] [ *Note:* a pointer to a const type can be the operand of a *delete-expression*; it is not necessary to cast away the constness (5.2.11) of the pointer expression before it is used as the operand of the *delete-expression*. — *end note* ]

C++14 5.3.5/3

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (*delete array*) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

Additionally, `void` is an incomplete type (C++14 3.9.1/9):

> The `void` type has an empty set of values. The `void` type is an incomplete type that cannot be completed. It is used as the return type for functions that do not return a value. Any expression can be explicitly converted to type *cv* `void` (5.4). An expression of type `void` shall be used only as an expression statement (6.2), as an operand of a comma expression (5.19), as a second or third operand of `?:` (5.16), as the operand of `typeid`, `noexcept`, or `decltype`, as the expression in a return statement (6.6.3) for a function with the return type `void`, or as the operand of an explicit conversion to type *cv* `void`.

---

Also, unless you're interfacing with a C API, `void*` is something you should strive to avoid completely.

Comment: I have the same opinion, but couldn't so far find the grounding in C++ standard or FAQ.

Comment: @Serge there you are. It's not an opinion ;)

Answer (score -2):

Not only it is illegal, it is simply a compilation error on modern compilers. Can't delete void*.

Comment: MSVC++2013 doesn't give me an error or even a warning (compiled at warning level 4).

Comment: I never had my hopes high for this compiler.

Comment: @SergeyA: It's not a compilation error with gcc 5.2.0 or clang 3.5.1, just a warning. Are those "modern" compilers?